# Pointers and string literals in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose, in C language I have the following code, where pointer variable "word" points to a string literal.

```
const char * word = "HELLO";
```

Why does this works -

```
printf("\nword[1]:  '%c'", word[1]);
printf("\nword[2]:  '%c'", word[2]);
```

and this doesn't ?

```
printf("\nAddress of word[1]:  %p", word[1]);
printf("\nAddress of word[2]:  %p", word[2]);
```

Comment: Well, `word[x]`  has a character type and not pointer... So your format specifiers are not matching. Why do you think it should work?

Comment: Use `&word[x]` to get the address for printing.

Comment: unrelated: prefer `printf("........\n");` as opposed to `printf("\n...");`.

Comment: You would have to add the & to get the pointer as using [] for arrays automatically dereferences the value

Comment: When you say `printf("\nAddress of word[1]:  %p", word[1]);` doesn't work, do you mean doesn't work as expected?  You're not having a compilation error, are you?

Comment: Each format specifier is associated with a particular type. %c is for type char and %p is for pointer types

Comment: Since, `word` is a pointer variable and it points to the address of first element, shouldn't `printf("\nAddress of word[1]:  %p", word[1]);` print the address of the 'word[1]' element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the latter is char not pointer. `word[1]` is the same as `*(word + 1)` and you just dereference the char pointer. The result is `char`

you need to:

```
printf("\nAddress of word[1]:  %p", (void *)&word[1]);
printf("\nAddress of word[2]:  %p", (void *)&word[2]);
```

or

```
printf("\nAddress of word[1]:  %p", (void *)(word + 1));
printf("\nAddress of word[2]:  %p", (void *)(word + 2));
```